# MySQL Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: timeout, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I've read all post with the same or very close headline, but still can't find a proper solution or explanation to my problem.

I'm working with MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE. I have been able to create a database with several tables, and create a conexion with python to write data to it. Still, I had a problem related to a varchar field that needed to be set to more than 45 characters. When I try to set it to bigger limits, like VARCHAR(70), no matter how many times I try, wether I set higher limits for timeout, I get the 2013 error, saying my connection was closed during the query.

I'm using the above version of workbench, on windows 10, and I'm trying to modify that field from the workbench. Afer that first time, I can't drop a table either, nor can I connect from python.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently what was happening is that I had a block, and there where a lot of query waiting in a situation of "waiting for table metadata block".

I did the following in the console of workbench

```
Select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where user='root'
```

that generates a list of all those processes. I copy that list in a new tab, and execute a massive kill of processes. After that it worked again.

Can anybody explain me how did I arrive to that situation and what precautions to take in my python scripts so as to avoid it?

Thnak you